# Replace the value of React env variable

Tags: node.js, reactjs, bash

I need to fetch data from API based on API environment. I also have ENV variable in .env file of react application, which has a default value. Is there a way, I can replace that value using with an npm script?

For now I am using approach, where I have env variables in .env file, and just switch it while building, using `REACT_APP_VARIABLE_NAME=value npm run build` But this value is temporary set only for current build or current session if app is launched locally. And I need to replace it permanently.

Would be grateful for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easier approach would be to add .env to .gitignore, then you use the file to set your environment locally. You could have another file with the default values you mentioned, like .env.sample, that one you can commit.

Another approach would be to use the env-cmd package, you could see an example here: https://dev.to/ninuvarghese/multiple-environments-in-create-react-app-dkj